# Create an Azure Internal Loadbalancer with Zone Redundant Properties

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-load-balancer

This is the command that I tried to use and the error message received is shown below the command

```
az network lb create --name <name> -g <RG name> --frotnend-ip-name <frontend_name> --frontend-ip-zone "1","2","3" -l southeastasia --private-ip-address <“static_ip”> --private-ip-address-version IPv4 --sku Standard --subnet “<subnet_id>” --subnet-address-prefix “<prefix>” --vnet-name “<vnet_name>” --public-ip-address “”
```

Below is the error received for the command

```
az network lb create: '1, 2, 3' is not a valid value for '--frontend-ip-zone'. Allowed values: 1, 2, 3.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first create the LB then add frontend-IP to the LB,

**Create LB:**

```
az network lb create -g MyResourceGroup -n MyLb --sku Standard
```

**Add Zone redundant frontend across Zones,**

```
az network lb frontend-ip create -g {rg} --lb-name lb -n LoadBalancerFrontEnd -z 1 2 3 --vnet-name vnet --subnet subnet
```

We are working on Public PR to enable this feature during the creation of LB itself.